# Using information from one table to find if the info exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, anti-join

I have 2 tables:

ads :

```
+------+---------------+
|  ID  |  Name         |
+------+---------------+
| 1    |   Item 1      |
| 2    |   Item 2      |
| 3    |   Item 3      |
| 4    |   Item 4      |
| 5    |   Item 5      |
+------+---------------+
```

assigned_ads :

```
+------+-----------+--------------+
|  ID  |   ad_id   |  location    |
+------+-----------+--------------+
|  1   |    3      |  place 1     |
|  2   |    2      |  place 2     |
|  3   |    1      |  place 3     |
+------+-----------+--------------+
```

As you can see; ad 1,2 and 3 are all assigned to a location. What I need is a query that gets all the the rows in the `ads` table that isn't assigned in the `assigned_ads` table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get non existing data from another Table (JOIN)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494586/get-non-existing-data-from-another-table-join)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to do this, as show below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads a
LEFT JOIN assigned_ads aa ON a.ID = aa.ad_id
WHERE aa.location IS NULL
```

Comment: "Need to"? As with most things in SQL, there is more than one way to perform relational non-existential qualification. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `NOT EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM assigned_ads aa WHERE a.ID = aa.ad_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The relational operator you require is semi difference a.k.a. [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29).

Most SQL products lacks an explicit semijoin operator or keyword. Standard SQL-92 doesn't have one (it has a `MATCH (subquery)` semijoin predicate but, although tempting to think otherwise, the semantics for `NOT MATCH (subquery)` are not the same as for semi difference; FWIW the truly relational language [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29) successfully uses the `NOT MATCHING` semi difference).

Semi difference can of course be written using other SQL predicates. The most commonly seen are: outer join with a test for nulls in the `WHERE` clause, closely followed by `EXISTS` or `IN (subquery)`. Using `EXCEPT` (equivalent to `MINUS` in Oracle) is another possible approach if your SQL product supports it and again depending on the data (specifically, when the headings of the two tables are the same).

Personally, I prefer to use `EXISTS` in SQL for semi difference join because the join clauses are closer together in the written code and doesn't result in projection over the joined table e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ads 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM assigned_ads
                    WHERE ads.ID = assigned_ads.ID
                  );
```

As with `IN (subquery)` (same for the outer join approach), you need to take extra care if the `WHERE` clause within the subquery involves nulls (hint: if `WHERE` clause in the subquery evaluates UNKNOWN due to the presence of nulls then it will be coerced to be FALSE by `EXISTS`, which may yield unexpected results).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT ad_id FROM assigned_ads)
```

Comment: a couple of typos in your query : 'assigned_ad' and 'om'

Answer (score 0):

just user left join query and match the left table id to null.
you query should look like this

```
select * from ads ad left join assigned_ad a_ad ON a_ad.ad_id = ad.id where a_ad.id is null
```

For more information about left join consult [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)