# SELECT statement comparing multiple fields from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, anti-join

I have to two seperate tables (Table A and Table B).
Table A has about 15 columns, the only ones of significance are [First Name] and [Last Name].
Table B has many more columns, and again the only ones I care about are FirstName and LastName  (Table B's fields do not contain spaces, where as Table A's do).

They're both in Access and I'm trying to write a query that will find people from Table B who are not in Table A. I'm quite amateur with SQL, but here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT ([Table A].[First Name] + [Table B].[Last Name]) AS FullName
FROM [Table A] 
LEFT JOIN [Table B] 
ON [Table A].FullName=[Table B].([First Name] + [Table B].[Last Name]) AS FullName
WHERE [Table A].FullName IS NULL;
```

It doesn't like me trying to make an alias for First Name + Last Name from Table B, but I have no idea how I'd do it otherwise.

Comment: The spaces in your database names make my brain hurt.

Comment: by spaces do you mean they are completely blank or do you mean that they have spaces in between the characters

Comment: I think that your paranthesis are in the wrong place.. in fact should shouldn't need any brackets in this query.

Comment: Have you tried it without aliasing it?

Comment: especially the ones on the 'ON' line just after [Table B] the [First Name] field belongs to TABLE B.. just remove all your brackets and you mind find that it works.

Comment: @user1096207 He was saying that making table and field names with spaces in them is a bad idea. It forces you to clutter up your queries with all those brackets.

Comment: Is there a required field in Table A?  Last Name, perhaps, or maybe an AutonumberID?

Comment: @JohnFx my comment was directed towards the OP

Comment: Sorry, so was mine . Used the wrong name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ([Table A].[First Name] + ' ' + [Table A].[Last Name]) AS FullName
FROM [Table B] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table A] 
ON [Table A].[First Name]=[Table B].[First Name] AND [Table B].[Last Name] = [Table A].[Last Name]
WHERE [Table A].[First Name] IS NULL AND [Table A].[Last Name] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ([Table A].[First Name] + [Table B].[Last Name]) AS FullName
FROM [Table A] 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [Table B] 
ON [Table A].FullName= ([Table B].([First Name] + [Table B].[Last Name])
WHERE [Table A].FullName IS NULL;
```

The key here is using an outer join, which will give you all records from Table B regardless of the join.  You can then filter it to the non-matching records by using the WHERE

Comment: This will find people in a table A who are not in table B, the reverse is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT [B].[First Name] & " " & [B].[Last Name] AS FullName
FROM TableB AS B
WHERE [B].[First Name] & " " & [B].[Last Name] NOT IN
(SELECT [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] FROM TableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: use `VIEW`s to remove those annoying spaces from the data element names, provide a consistent naming and concatenate the full name attributes e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW TableA
AS
SELECT [First Name] AS first_name, 
       [Last Name] AS last_name,
       first_name + ' ' + last_name AS full_name
  FROM [Table A];


CREATE VIEW TableB
AS
SELECT FirstName AS first_name, 
       LastName AS last_name,
       first_name + ' ' + last_name AS full_name
  FROM [Table B];

SELECT *
  FROM TableB AS B
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM TableA AS A
                    WHERE B.full_name = A.full_name
                  );
```

Note `CREATE VIEW` requires [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0) e.g. use an ADO connection.

p.s. the operator for "people from Table B who are not in Table A" is known as [semi difference a.k.a. antijoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494586/get-non-existing-data-from-another-table-join/7496263#7496263).

Comment: This query is taking ages to process, I have the latest Phpmyadmin and Navicat and both get stuck when I execute the last one. I need something like this but perhaps faster? I have 50K+ records and I am comparing tableA/B on a column that contains a string 200Characters.. Any suggestion for this case ? Thanks