# SQL Minus in SQL Compact for large datasets

Tags: c#, sql, performance, sql-server-ce

I have two large tables:

```
products
--------
id (char) (primary key)
somefield1 (char)
somefield2 (char)
```

and

```
expired_products
------
id (char) (primary key)
```

I want to only have those ids which are in products but are not expired (id not in expired_products). In MS Access I would do something like this

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products LEFT JOIN expired_products ON products.id = expired_products.id
WHERE expired_products.id Is Null;
```

Ultimately, I want to write the result of the query into a new table.

Is there any better (faster query) solution in SQL Server Compact (sdf file)?

Btw. I am using C# and using the SqlCeConnection to access the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table new_table (
    id char(7) -- same as primary key in products
)
```

This is command to execute in C#, it's "[insert into ... select ...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174633.aspx)" statement:

```
insert into new_table (id)
select p.id
from products p
where not exists (select 1 from expired_products e.id = p.id)
```

**Added** after comment:

[INSERT (SQL Server Compact) on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174633.aspx)

```
INSERT [INTO] 
      table_name  [ ( column_list ) ] 
      { VALUES 
      ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n] ) 
| derived_table
       }
```

From MSDN:

*derived_table*
Any valid **SELECT** statement that returns rows of data to be inserted into the table.

Comment: But insert into is not supported by SQL Server Compact

Comment: @ErikEJ, I've based on info that I've added in answer.

Answer (score 4):

The minus operator in Standard SQL and SQL Server is `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM products
EXCEPT
SELECT id 
  FROM expired_products;
```

...but it seems that `EXCEPT` is not supported in Compact 4.0 :(

As ever with SQL, that are alternative ways of performing [semi difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494586/get-non-existing-data-from-another-table-join/7496263#7496263):

e.g. `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
  FROM products AS p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM expired_products AS e
                    WHERE p.id = e.id
                  );
```

e.g. `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
  FROM products
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM expired_products);
```

Comment: But EXCEPT is not supported by SQL Server Compact

Comment: @ErikEJ: I've updated my answer. Care to cast some votes around here? ;)