# What's the ActiveRecord way to search for nulls in a join?

Tags: sql, activerecord, join

Suppose I have three tables in my Rails app: `cats`, `dogs`, and `owners`. I want to find all the cats whose owners do **not** also have dogs.

With SQL, I could do the following:

```
SELECT
  `cats`.*
FROM
  `cats`
  LEFT JOIN `dogs` ON `cats`.`owner_id` = `dogs`.`owner_id`
WHERE
  `dogs`.`id` IS NULL;
```

However, I'd like to do this as a chainable scope on `Cat`. The closest I've gotten so far is `Cat.connection.select_all(query_string)`, but that's not chainable.

What's the ActiveRecord way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but the relational operator you are describing is known as [semi difference (also antijoin)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494586/get-non-existing-data-from-another-table-join/7496263#7496263). 'Search for nulls in [an outer] join' is but one way of writing semi difference using SQL, perhaps ActiveRecord has multiple ways too?

Comment: @onedaywhen - interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cat.joins("LEFT JOIN `dogs` ON `cats`.`owner_id` = `dogs`.`owner_id`").where("`dogs`.`id` IS NULL")
```

Or if you want it as a scope:

```
scope :cats_without_dogs, joins("LEFT JOIN `dogs` ON `cats`.`owner_id` = `dogs`.`owner_id`").where("`dogs`.`id` IS NULL")
```