# Can someone explain this query

Tags: sql, oracle

here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM customers  
WHERE 
     NOT EXISTS 
     (     
          SELECT 1 FROM brochure_requests     
          WHERE  brochure_requests.first_name = customers.customer_first_name AND    
          brochure_requests.last_name = customers.customer_last_name
     )
```

This query works just fine but I am not sure why it works. In the NOT EXISTS part `SELECT 1` what is the **1** for. When I ran this query

```
select 1 from test2
```

Here were the results:

```
1
-----
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
..
```

How does the not exists query work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is smart enough to ignore the actual `SELECT` in an `EXISTS`. So, basically, if it WOULD return rows because the filters match, that is all it cares about...the `SELECT` portion of the `EXISTS` never executes. It only uses the EXISTS clauses for evaluation purposes

I had this misconception for quite some time since you will see this `SELECT 1` a lot. But, I have seen 42, *, etc....It never actually cares about the result, only that there would be one :). The key to keep in mind that SQL is a compiled language, so it will optimize this appropriately.

You could put a 1/0 and it will not throw a divide-by-zero exception...thus further proving that the result set is not evaluated. This is shown in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e038e/2)

Code from Fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE test (i int)
CREATE TABLE test2 (i int)

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1)

SELECT i
FROM test
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1/0
  FROM test2
  WHERE test2.i = test.i
)
```

And finally, more to your point, the `NOT` simply negates an `EXISTS`, saying to IGNORE any rows that match

Answer (score 1):

The subquery is a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) joining between the `customers` and `brochure_requests` tables on the selected fields.

The `EXISTS` clause is simply a predicate that will only return the matching rows (and the `NOT` negates that).

Answer (score 0):

The query :

```
select 1 from test2
```

shows you the value 1 as the value for all the records in test2 table.

Every `SELECT` query must have at least one column.  I think that's why an unnamed column, which has the value 1, is used here.

The sub-query gives you the rows of the related Customers from the table `brochure_requests`.

`NOT EXISTS` causes the main query to return all the rows from the `Customers` table, which are not in the table `brochure_requests`.

Answer (score 0):

The relational operator in question is known as ['antijoin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494586/get-non-existing-data-from-another-table-join/7496263#7496263) (alternatively 'not match' or 'semi difference'). In natural language: customers who do not match brochure_requests using the common attributes first_name and last_name.

A closely related operator is relational difference (alternatively 'minus' or 'except') e.g. in SQL

```
SELECT customer_last_name, customer_first_name
  FROM customers  
EXCEPT
SELECT last_name, first_name  
  FROM brochure_requests;
```

Answer (score -1):

if customer requested a brochure, subquery returns 1 for this customer. and this customer not be added to return resultset. bcouse of NOT EXISTS clause.

Comment: the subquery does not actually return anything

Answer (score -1):

Note: I don't know Oracle, and am not especially expert in SQL.

However, `SELECT 1 from` simply returns a `1` for every row matching the `from` clause. So the inner `select` can find a `brochure_requests` row whose name fields match those of the `customer` row currently being considered, it will produce a `1` result and fail the `NOT EXISTS`.

Hence the query selects all `customers` who do not have a `brochure_request` matching their name.

Comment: The thing to note is that the SELECT portion is never evaluated, so it will not actually produce a 1

Answer (score -2):

For each row of the table `Customers`, the query returns the rows when the `sub-query`.
`NOT EXISTS` returns no row.

If the sub-query in `NOT EXISTS` returns rows, then the rows of the table `Customers` are not returned.

Comment: The subquery does not actually return anything. It merely is used for evaluation purposes