# How to use SQL UNION

Tags: php, sql

well i do not know how to use sql union properly . 
i have two tables with domains(url) i want to compare table1 with table2 so that i get unique domain from table 2 which is not in table 1.

example

**table1**

```
id   domain
1    google.com
2    facebook
3    stackoverflow.com
```

**table2**

```
id   domain
1    youtube.com
2    facebook
3    stackoverflow.com
```

so i want that i compare both tables and get youtube.com because its not in table1
i used sql union like that

```
$query="SELECT table1.domain, table2.domain "."FROM table1, table2 "."WHERE table1.domain != table2.domain";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$new_url=$rec["domain"];
}
```

now i get double results like   youtube.com  youtube.com 
so help whats wrong with my sql statement

Comment: You need to use a JOIN, not a UNION

Comment: Why do you use the . separator in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT t2.domain FROM
table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t2.domain = t1.domain
WHERE t1.domain IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL that you're looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.domain FROM t1
WHERE domain not in (SELECT t2.domain FROM t2)
```

Comment: See Marco's answer, it is far faster on most DBMS's

Comment: @dtech Yes, I know. I only provide a different kind of solution... Read it like "logic training" :)

Answer (score 0):

The relational operator you require is difference (union is analogous to addition). In standard SQL the keyword is `EXCEPT` (in Oracle it is `MINUS`, which is a little more intuitive IMO):

```
SELECT domain
  FROM table2
EXCEPT 
SELECT domain
  FROM table1
```

Does the 'php' tag imply MySQL? MySQL lacks an explicit relational difference operator, so you would need to use an [antijoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494586/get-non-existing-data-from-another-table-join/7496263#7496263) construct.